# Type annotation for glob generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, generator

My function is supposed to return a generator that yields files of a specific signature via `Path` from the `pathlib` module. The problem is that I don't understand how to properly annotate the function in Python 3.

Here is the function:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generator

def get_waves_generator(directory: str) -> ???:
    gen = Path(directory).rglob('*.wav')
    return gen
```

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264250/how-to-annotate-a-generator-in-python3), which is essentially a copy from the docs. I need to annotate it with the following

```
Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]
```

What are the `YieldType`, `SendType` and `ReturnType` in my case?

Comment: The ```YieldType``` is likely ```pathlib.PosixPath```. If the generator only yields values, the other two types are None. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator.

Comment: Thanks, it matches closely also what @fepegar answered, though you are right about the type (it's `pathlib.PosixPath`, not `Path`). Would you like to provide this as the answer?

Comment: `pathlib.PosixPath` is a subclass of `pathlib.Path`. If you instantiate a path with `Path("path/to/file")` you get a `PosixPath` on a Unix machine, and a `WindowsPath` on Win. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator):

> A generator can be annotated by the generic type `Generator[YieldType,
>   SendType, ReturnType]`. For example:
>
> ```
> def echo_round() -> Generator[int, float, str]:
>     sent = yield 0
>     while sent >= 0:
>         sent = yield round(sent)
>     return 'Done'
> ```
>
> Note that unlike many other generics in the typing module, the
>   `SendType` of `Generator` behaves contravariantly, not covariantly or
>   invariantly.
>
> If your generator will only yield values, set the `SendType` and
>   `ReturnType` to None:
>
> ```
> def infinite_stream(start: int) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
>     while True:
>         yield start
>         start += 1
> ```

As that generator is returning instances of `pathlib.Path`, you can do

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generator

def get_waves_generator(directory: str) -> Generator[Path, None, None]:
    gen = Path(directory).rglob('*.wav')
    return gen
```

Comment: Thanks! It's close, one mistake I guess is what Eric mentioned: the type is `pathlib.PosixPath`. Upvote nonetheless, but I don't think I can accept the answer as it stands (still learning the rules of the forum, so please correct me if anything). EDIT: I actually can't upvote unless I get 15+ points...

Comment: Isn't `PosixPath` specific to Unix though? See this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647584/how-to-test-if-object-is-a-pathlib-path

Comment: I could only test it on Linux, hence my comment. I think you're right though. PosixPath is inheriting from Path. Sorry for the confusion, I think you can change it back.